# How to show something similar to an alert like SO does here with javascript?

Tags: javascript, alert

How to show something similar to an alert like SO does here with javascript?

Comment: This is what he wants to see: http://i28.tinypic.com/omp3a.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you'll need to do **[ajax polling](http://nickriggs.com/index.php/posts/simple-ajax-polling-plugin-for-jquery/)** for the "*load new answers*" alert that appears whilst you are writing an answer.

Here's a [nice tutorial for ASP.NET](http://www.clientsideasp.net/2009/03/01/aspnet-ajax-poll-using-jquery-a-complete-implementation-with-admin-part/) using jQuery

For the alert when you attempt to navigate away from a page when you have started typing an answer/ editing a post, look at the `onunload` event. A [`confirm`](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php) dialog is used as opposed to an [`alert`](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptalert.php)

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about SO warning you when you try to navigate away from a page with a partially filled in comment/answer ? Check out the `onunload()` method in Javascript. See [here](http://www.codetoad.com/javascript/miscellaneous/onunload_event.asp) for an example.

Comment: I mean what the popup dialog really is?It's similar to an alert,but it's not.

Comment: I think your question may need rephrasing or clarification

Answer (score 0):

add this script to the head portion of your page:

```
<script language="javascript">
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', onUnload, false);
  function onUnload(e)
  {
    e.returnValue = "some Text";//this is your message
    e.preventDefault();
  }
</script>
```